# My Java method is not printing anything - Print all possible subsets of a number without repetition

Tags: java

I wrote this code to print all possible subsets of permutation, without repetition, of a number (n) but I cannot figure out why nothing is printing
i.e- for n = 3, is should output:
123
132
213
231
312
321

Here is the code I wrote:

```
public static void printAllPerm(int n)  {

          int [] A = new int[n+1];
          printAllRec(n, 0, A);

       }

    public static void printAllRec(int n, int i, int [] A)  {

          if ( promising(i, A) ) {
            if(i == n){         
                for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                   System.out.print(A[j] + "  ");
                System.out.println();
            }   

          else
          {
             for (A[1] = 1; A[1] <= n; A[1]++)  {
                A[i+1] = A[1];
                printAllRec(n, i+1, A);
             }

          }
       }

    }//void printAllRec(int n, int i, int [] A)


    public static boolean promising(int n, int [] myArray)
    {
        for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
                if ( (i != j) && ( myArray[i] == myArray[j]) )
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return true;    
    }
```

*** The method promising simply checks if a number is repeated
i.e- 112 is not allowed, all numbers have to be different

Comment: What happens when you run it ina debugger step by step?  I can't see any obvious problems but there clearly are bugs somewhere.

Comment: I went through it with a debugger. I'm having a hard time understanding what you expect to happen at each of those if statements. This code seems overly convoluted to me for its functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies here

```
 if ( promising(i, A) )
```

Here you are passing `0` as `i` due to which `promising` function returns false and nothing gets printed.

Comment: yeah but I should print once i == n. I am incrementing i with 1 in printAllRec(n, i+1, A) then recalling promising till i == n then should print

Answer (score 0):

In `printAllRec(..)` at `A[i+1] = A[1]`, your code always ends up with an array with the same number twice just before you call `promising(..)` thus your print statement never gets called.

Write some tests for `printAllRec(..)` so you can tweak it to do what you're after.